# I have an text input inside a div, how do I get the background of the div to change when the input has focus?

Tags: css

```
<div class="contain">
 <input type="text">
</div>
```

So... there is basically what I have.

I have a background of the div to be one thing, but I want to change it when the input gains focus... like change the background to image to the same image as before, but with an X at the right for clearing the text field.

How do I do taht with CSS? (just the background switching)

Comment: Well, you can't as the `input` is a child of the `div`. Why not use some kind of overlay element with the `input`?

Comment: If you're already using jQuery on the site, you should use that for this. Otherwise, let me know and I'll write an answer that's as close as you can get without JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't trigger an element's CSS change on interaction with another element simply with CSS.

Here's a simple [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com) solution which accomplishes your goal:

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('focused');
}).blur(function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass('focused');
});
```

Working demo 1 (with background colors): http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/V2hub/

Working demo 2 (with background images): http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/V2hub/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with pure css. Either use javascript - jquery way: `$("#yourInput").focus(function(){$(this).parent().addClass("focused")})` or add padding or border to your input, and set background image on input itself if you want to stick to pure css. You may need to alter the image, to fake input look.

Answer (score 0):

```
#element:focus { background:url(img.png); }
```

More info: http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Test/CSS3/Selectors/current/html/full/flat/css3-modsel-20.html

Comment: That affects the `input`, not the `div`, assuming `input` has that ID.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach. With pure css. At first I was thinking about using pseudo-element, but it looks like pseudo-elemnts don't go well with input elements. So instead of using something like `input:focus:after` which won't work (at least in firefox) I used simple `div`.

```
.contain { position:relative; }
input:focus + div { position: absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%: z-index:-1; background: red; }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E9nwU/).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.contain:has(input:focus){
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
 <input type="text">
</div>
```